# ¿Cómo imprimir código HTML con PHP sin que se muestre como texto simple?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html5, bootstrap

Estoy realizando la siguiente consulta a la base de datos y como resultado obtendo un número de filas y columnas. Intento imprimirlos como código **HTML** y éste solo se muestra como texto simple dentro de una etiqueta `<pre></pre>`.

**Código PHP:**

```php
function getLista() {
  $marca = new Marca('SELECT');
  $id = /*$_POST['id']*/'1';

  $sql = "SELECT mar_id , mar_nombre FROM sys_alm_marca m INNER JOIN sys_alm_categoria_producto c
                  ON c.cat_id = m.cat_id WHERE c.cat_id = '".$id."'";

  $result = $marca->selectForSql($sql);
  $opcciones = '<option value="0">Elige una opción</option>';
  foreach ($result as $row){
    echo "<option value='".$row->mar_id."'>".$row->mar_nombre."</option>";
  }

  return $opcciones;
}

echo getLista();
```

**Código HTML:**

```html
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
    <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">
      <option value="0">Elige una opción</option>
      <option value='5'>TK TYRE</option>
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con imprimir como código HTML?, si ya obtuviste los resultados de la base de datos entonces necesitas simplemente imprimirlos a través de PHP para que se vea en una página Web.

Comment: El problema es que quieres hacer algo usando un elemento que existe para hacer precisamente lo contrario de lo que quieres. Me refiero a `<pre>`, que [existe para imprimir texto HTML preformateado](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/pre). Si quitas la etiqueta `<pre></pre>` que rodea tu contenido el texto deberá verse normal. Imagino que esos `option` están dentro de un `select`.

Comment: El que puso lo de los <select> dio una respuesta sencilla pero no la veo incorrecta. Esta imprimiendo puros <option>, no deberian ir dentro de una etiqueta Select? por otro lado, la consulta a la DB traera resultados, pero esa funcion no imprime ninguno. Solo imprime ``'<option value="0">Elige una opción</option>';`` No deberia hacer un <select></select> en el html, dentro escribir el unico option con value vacio, y que la funcion imprima dentro de estos select (abajo del primer option) el resultado del foreach?

Comment: Sería bueno que especifiques si quieres armar un select o mostrar código HTML con coloreado de sintáxis que, de ser el caso, solo necesitas: https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.highlight-string.php

Answer (score 2):

¿No deberías poner unas etiquetas **SELECT** en tu código **HTML** y solo retornar las etiquetas `<option>` desde el **PHP**?

**Por ejemplo:**

```html
<body>
<!--Acá reemplacé «<pre></pre>» por «<select></select>»,-->
<!--entendiendo que las etiquetas «<option></option>»-->
<!--van dentro de las «<select>» -->
  <select>
    <option value="0">Elige una opción</option>
    <?php getLista(); ?>
  </select>
</body>
```

**Mientras que en PHP:**

```php
function getLista() {
  $marca = new Marca('SELECT');
  $id = /*$_POST['id']*/ '1';

  $sql = "SELECT mar_id , mar_nombre FROM sys_alm_marca m
    INNER JOIN sys_alm_categoria_producto c
    ON c.cat_id = m.cat_id WHERE c.cat_id = '".$id."'";

  $result = $marca->selectForSql($sql);

  // Eliminé «opcciones» y solo imprimí utilizando
  // la sentencia «foreach»:
  foreach( $result as $row ) {
    echo "<option value='".$row->mar_id."'>".$row->mar_nombre."</option>";
  }

}
```

Tu código **HTML** debería poder renderizarse más o menos así:

```html
<body>
  <select>
    <option value="0">Elige una opción</option>
    <option value="1">NOMBRE DE LA MARCA 1</option>
    <option value="2">NOMBRE DE LA MARCA 2</option>
    ...
    <option value="n">NOMBRE DE LA MARCA n</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Entiendo que es eso lo que buscabas.